# Changing script from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I get this code to show in one line? It currently shows one line on top of the other and it is throwing off my format.If possible I would like it to all be in one line. I am not an expert in coding so clear explanation of how to do it would be appreciated.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="company-homepagetime" valign="top">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function getClockTime()
                {
                    var now    = new Date();
                    var hour   = now.getHours();
                    var minute = now.getMinutes();
                    var second = now.getSeconds();
                    var ap = "<span class='company-homepagetime-ampm'>AM</span>";
                    if (hour   > 11) { ap = "<span class='company-homepagetime-ampm'>PM</span>";}
                    if (hour   > 12) { hour = hour - 12;      }
                    if (hour   == 0) { hour = 12;             }
                    if (minute < 10) { minute = "0" + minute; }
                    if (second < 10) { second = "0" + second; }
                    var timeString = hour +
                        ':' +
                        minute +
                        " " +
                        ap;
                    return timeString;
                } // function getClockTime()
                    var clockTime = getClockTime();
                    document.write(clockTime);
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="company-homepagedate" valign="top">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var months=new Array(13);
                months[1]="January";
                months[2]="Febuary";
                months[3]="March";
                months[4]="April";
                months[5]="May";
                months[6]="June";
                months[7]="July";
                months[8]="August";
                months[9]="September";
                months[10]="October";
                months[11]="November";
                months[12]="December";
                var day=new Date();
                var lmonth=months[day.getMonth() + 1];
                var date=day.getDate();
                var year = day.getFullYear();
                document.write(lmonth + " " + date + ", " + year);
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just take this section out of the middle as shown below. `</td></tr><tr><td class="company-homepagedate" valign="top">`

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in the same td like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="company-homepagetime" valign="top">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function getClockTime()
                {
                    var now    = new Date();
                    var hour   = now.getHours();
                    var minute = now.getMinutes();
                    var second = now.getSeconds();
                    var ap = "<span class='company-homepagetime-ampm'>AM</span>";
                    if (hour   > 11) { ap = "<span class='company-homepagetime-ampm'>PM</span>";}
                    if (hour   > 12) { hour = hour - 12;      }
                    if (hour   == 0) { hour = 12;             }
                    if (minute < 10) { minute = "0" + minute; }
                    if (second < 10) { second = "0" + second; }
                    var timeString = hour +
                        ':' +
                        minute +
                        " " +
                        ap;
                    return timeString;
                } // function getClockTime()
                    var clockTime = getClockTime();
                    document.write(clockTime);
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var months=new Array(13);
                months[1]="January";
                months[2]="Febuary";
                months[3]="March";
                months[4]="April";
                months[5]="May";
                months[6]="June";
                months[7]="July";
                months[8]="August";
                months[9]="September";
                months[10]="October";
                months[11]="November";
                months[12]="December";
                var day=new Date();
                var lmonth=months[day.getMonth() + 1];
                var date=day.getDate();
                var year = day.getFullYear();
                document.write(lmonth + " " + date + ", " + year);
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]